# how to prevent auto register avro schema for sink kafka topic in kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry

I have a kafka stream that reads from one topic an produces to multiple topics ... sink topics are multi type topic ... meaning that they should accept different type of messages. When the stream wtire to the sink topic it overrides the schema definition on the schema registry with the first message type that is written to the topic.

I have the property for kafka stream config

```
auto.register.schemas = false
```

but the value schema on the registry for the sink topic is override anyway. How can I prevent the schema on registry to be overridden?